# Почему работает, но не так, как надо?

Tags: c#

Программа для турфирмы. На главной Форме ДатаГрид, в него выводятся договоры. При отрисовке, делаю розовым фон строк (договоров), у которых до вылета осталось меньше пяти дней и клиент ещё не оплатил.

Некоторые строки действительно становятся розовыми, но, когда я начал их проверять, оказалось, что не понятно, по какому принципу они раскрашиваются :) в общем раскрашиваются как строки, соответствующие условию, так и нет... Беда в том, что я уже несколько часов не могу найти свою ошибку :(

```
private void dgTours_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int intTourID = (int)dgTours.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
            DataTable table = mainDataSet.Tables["Tours"];
            DataRow[] rws = table.Select("ID = " + intTourID);
            DataRow rw = rws[0];
            if (rw["TourDate"] != DBNull.Value && rw["Cost"] != DBNull.Value && rw["PayFromTour"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                DateTime dtDate = (DateTime)rw["TourDate"];
                TimeSpan tsTime = dtDate - DateTime.Now;
                decimal dcmlCost = (decimal)rw["Cost"];
                decimal dcmlPay = (decimal)rw["PayFromTour"];
                if (dcmlPay < dcmlCost && tsTime.Days < 5)
                {
                    dgTours.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы в visual studio работаете? Если да то попробуйте пробежаться отладчиком по данной функции, думаю все станет на свои места.

Comment: Поддерживаю, это единственный способ узнать в чем ошибка.
У меня тоже такая проблема была, как у автора. Проблема оказалась в несрабатывании события выделения строки в гриде - 1 раз  не сработала, потом сработала... Проблема оказалась в  "DefaultCellStyle", есть еще другой способ, поищите, не помню как я делал(((

Comment: Оказалось, всё правильно работает. Просто у фирмы, оказывается есть такие клиенты, от которых требуется оплата меньше, чем стоит тур. В общем, особенность производства :)